# my ajax code is not sending data to server and get response

Tags: php, html, ajax

Why is my PHP AJAX code not working? I am a PHP newcomer and just started learning AJAX.

#### index.html:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function sendmessage(str) {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
          xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
          alert("failed");
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "myserver.php?name=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input type="button" value='ok' onclick="sendmessage('ssss')">
  </body>
</html>
```

#### Server side code (myserver.php)

```php
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Server1</h1>
    <?php
          $q=$_GET['name']; 
          echo "Server ran successfully data is $q";
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

I just want my code to send data 'ssss' to the server and server reply adding  additional message which I then show client side.

I can see the message within the developer tool but not on the web page. How should I proceed ?

Comment: How do you know it is not sendiing? Have you watched the request/response in the browser's developer tools ?

Comment: The client is sending a parameter called "name".  The server is looking for a parameter called "q".

Comment: And you did absolutely nothing to show any response on the client side, so far you are just sending the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to think of AJAX as a "conversaton" between the two pages : 'index.html' is asking a question (request) to 'server.php' and expects an answer. It is an exchange.

Now, what you have succeeded is to make the first part, asking the question. But now, your "index.html" page is waiting for the answer. It can be text, xml, Json... but it is expecting an answer to make changes on itself with javascript. This answer is given by 'server.php' file. For example, right now you are answering to 'index.html' page the following string

> "Server ran successfully data is $q"

take a look at these basic examples of how to check for responses https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_response.asp and if something is still unclear, u can comment below

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to change your $_GET[] method parameter.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Server1</h1>
    <?php
    $q=intval($_GET['name']));
    echo "Server ran successfully data is $q";
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $q=$_GET['name'];  echo "Server ran successfully data is $q";
```

you have to change server file code with this code and you can check your console. it is working